# create graph in excel with only part of values

Tags: excel

I want to create graph in excell.

I have 400000 rows, so the graph is very thick and isn't looking like a line (the values really similar to each other).

Is there any way to choose 1 row out of 10 for every point the graph considers, so my graph will have only 40k rows out of 400k?

I hope my question was understable, thx!

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to add an extra column to the data, you could use this formula

```
=MOD(ROW(),10)=0
```

and copy down, then filter for TRUE on the new column. Graphs do respect filtering so that would give a you a graph with 40K points.